# How can we connect php applications with cloud storage?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

We configure PHP applications on 2 servers with databases in CloudSQL, they require read /write static content in a CloudStorage bucket from PHP applications.

What I did was install GCS Fuse to mount the CloudStorage bucket as a shared folder on a server but PHP applications do not see the bucket files. Review service account, API access is enabled and can be viewed with GSUTIL. In the support forums mention some bookstores but I really do not understand, they also mention solutions in App Engine but it does not apply in this case.

The question is if there is another way to connect PHP applications with Cloud Storage?

Comment: Please ask your question in english, as that's what most users on stackoverflow speak.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, I've voted to reopen it.